# InputStream is null when trying to read a resource file

Tags: java, maven

I have a JSON file in `/src/main/resources` which I'm trying to read in the following way:

```
private List<String> readContextFromFile(String file) {

        List<String> context = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
            Map<String, ArrayList> input = objectMapper.readValue(in, HashMap.class);

            context = input.get("@context");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error reading value {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return context;
    }
```

However, InputStream is null.

This is the file path that I pass: `/resources/context.json`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the file in the same folder of where the class is?

Comment: vc73, yes, it is.

Comment: The `src` directory isn't there at runtime. Have a look at where the resource actually is in your JAR or WAR file, and use that path.

Answer (score 1):

1) `/src/main/resources` represents the source code, not the runtime code.
Compiled classes and processed resources ends in the `target/classes` folder not in the `src` folder.

2) About :

> This is the file path that I pass: `/resources/context.json`

Why do you pass the `resources` token ?  It is a Maven/Gradle directory that you will not retrieve at runtime. Only which is contained inside will be available at runtime.
What you want to pass is `/context.json`.

Comment: when I pass /context.json, InputStream again is null.

Comment: Recompile your code (`mvn compile`) and check that `target/classes` contains the `context.json` file. Retry.

Comment: @ davidxxx this works. Thank you!